# How could Git be exploited using an SHA-1 collision?

Tags: hash, sha, git

Now that Google has created an SHA-1 collision, I've been wondering how this affects Git, which is still using SHA-1 for some reason. What would happen if there were two objects with the same hash, and how could this be exploited?

Comment: And a related question on StackOverflow: [How would git handle a SHA-1 collision on a blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392365/how-would-git-handle-a-sha-1-collision-on-a-blob)